# advanced unix command-line trick

Tags: linux, unix, command, redhat

I want help regarding unix command line.

In command line if i type any command like date; konsole should automatically execute ls and than execute date.
example: if i type date
than interface should be like **ls ; date**. 
I can do alias but i want not only for date for every other command also. even if i don't supply any command and press empty enter it should execute ls.

I tried confugiring in set prompt variable. but i didn't got it and the variable is not reloading automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using `konsole` as your terminal emulator and `tclsh` as your interactive shell?  If so, the former is irrelevant and the latter is an interesting tool choice.  More likely, you are running bash as your interactive shell, in which case you can simply add a trap on DEBUG.  To test the behavior type:

```
trap ls DEBUG
```

After executing this in bash, in this shell only, `ls` will be executed before every command.  If this is the behavior you want, set the trap in `~/.bashrc`.

Note that this is bash specific.  Other shells have different mechanisms for getting this behavior.